# Command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 when installing pydeep

Tags: gcc, centos

I am trying to install pydeep via `pip install pydeep` on a CentOS 64b, but i get this:
`error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`. Tried to install gcc and many others like python-dev, etc. but still no result. I also cloned it from GitHub and tried to:
`python setup.py build` but I get the same problem (note that I already have libssdeep).

```
Downloading/unpacking pydeep
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pydeep
Installing collected packages: pydeep
  Running setup.py install for pydeep
    building 'pydeep' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c pydeep.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/pydeep.o
    pydeep.c:2:19: error: fuzzy.h: No such file or directory
    pydeep.c: In function ‘pydeep_hash_file’:
    pydeep.c:33: error: ‘FUZZY_MAX_RESULT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    pydeep.c:33: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    pydeep.c:33: error: for each function it appears in.)
    pydeep.c:38: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fuzzy_hash_file’
    pydeep.c: In function ‘pydeep_hash_buf’:
    pydeep.c:64: error: ‘FUZZY_MAX_RESULT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    pydeep.c:72: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fuzzy_hash_buf’
    pydeep.c: In function ‘pydeep_compare’:
    pydeep.c:90: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fuzzy_compare’
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-bogdan/pydeep/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-EQweL1-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
    running install

running build

running build_ext

building 'pydeep' extension

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c pydeep.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/pydeep.o

pydeep.c:2:19: error: fuzzy.h: No such file or directory

pydeep.c: In function ‘pydeep_hash_file’:

pydeep.c:33: error: ‘FUZZY_MAX_RESULT’ undeclared (first use in this function)

pydeep.c:33: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

pydeep.c:33: error: for each function it appears in.)

pydeep.c:38: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fuzzy_hash_file’

pydeep.c: In function ‘pydeep_hash_buf’:

pydeep.c:64: error: ‘FUZZY_MAX_RESULT’ undeclared (first use in this function)

pydeep.c:72: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fuzzy_hash_buf’

pydeep.c: In function ‘pydeep_compare’:

pydeep.c:90: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fuzzy_compare’

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-bogdan/pydeep/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-EQweL1-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-bogdan/pydeep
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

If you need the full log or some specific info, I`ll provide it ASAP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have `libssdeep-dev` or something like that?

Comment: Yes, installed it too.

Comment: Then you need to figure out where `fuzzy.h` is, where gcc is looking for it, and why that's not the same.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I managed to make it work after hard times. Indeed that `fuzzy` was the problem.

Problem solved!

Answer (score 10):

For anyone else stumbling on this, running the following fixed the pydeep compile problems for me in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libfuzzy-dev
```

pydeep's setup.py needs to be run as root